# Return one result from query statement using inner join

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have two tables;Lecturers Table and Courses Table.

```
myStr2 = "CREATE TABLE Lecturers (lec_no VARCHAR(3), name VARCHAR(30), email VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY(lec_no))"
myStr3 = "CREATE TABLE Courses (course_code VARCHAR(6), course_name VARCHAR(30), lec_no VARCHAR(3), PRIMARY KEY(course_code), FOREIGN KEY(lec_no) REFERENCES Lecturers(lec_no))"
```

I would like to create a query to return the name of the lecturer teaching a certain course.The result should only return the name of the lecturer and nothing else. I created a function to do this. Here is my code:

```
def get_lecturer(self,course_code):
        self.course_code = course_code
        self.myCursor.execute("SELECT name FROM Lecturers WHERE course_code = (?) IN (SELECT name, course_code FROM Lecturers, Courses WHERE Lecturers.lec_no = Courses.lec_no"),(self.course_code))    
        return self.myCursor.fetchall()
```

When I do this I get an error of invalid syntax. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put both WHERE expressions into the same query:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM Lecturers, Courses
WHERE Lecturers.lec_no = Courses.lec_no
  AND course_code = ?
```

But a join is better written with JOIN:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM Lecturers
JOIN Courses USING (lec_no)
WHERE course_code = ?
```

Alternatively, you could also use IN, of you really want to use a subquery (but if the subquery is known to return a single value, you should replace `IN` with `=`):

```sql
SELECT name
FROM Lecturers
WHERE lec_no IN (SELECT lec_no
                 FROM Courses
                 WHERE course_code = ?)
```